# Suppress space for label in Lightning component in a table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

My component has this lightning:select input component on it and I cannot suppress the label section. I see what slds css is being added but I can’t seem to prevent it.

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-7 slds-border_bottom">
    <lightning:select name="isCredit" value="{!item.b1}" class="slds-form-element_horizontal" variant="label-hidden">
        <option value="false">Debit</option>
        <option value="true">Credit</option>
    </lightning:select>
</div>
```

It looks like this, and you can see the html it created of the right.

[image: Auto Generated CSS]

When I manually remove the slds-form-element__control from the class list it properly fills the space.

[image: Unwanted CSS Removed]

How do I prevent or override salesforce from automatically adding the slds-form-element__control css to the input select when I truly want to hide the label?